# Dark Souls P2DE: Little shining worm

Tags: dark-souls

I'm playing Dark Souls on PC. I'm after fight with demon taurus. I've got 2 questions. First is that I destroyed some barrels in tower which leds to him, and I noticed little shiny worm, I killed it and it dropped some titanit, what is that worm ? It spawns randomly ?

Second Question is demon taurus related. I read somewhere that he can drop some kind of axe, but It didn't drop for me. It's random chance ?

Comment: Is what you saw a crystal lizard? http://darksouls.wikidot.com/crystal-lizard

Comment: Oh, yea, that was that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creature you probably saw (confirmed in comment) was a crystal lizard.

I have not played dark souls, I am still trying to get through demon souls ng+, but by my research they behave similar to crystal lizards from demon souls. They spawn in the same spot a number of times per play through equal to 1+the number of bosses you have defeated in the area.

http://darksouls.wikidot.com/crystal-lizard

The axe you mention being droped from the demon taurus is the "Demon's Greataxe"

http://darksouls.wikidot.com/demon-s-greataxe

It is a rare drop from the monster, but is available for purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Have 10 humanities and ring that boosts item discovery and you’ll get the demon great axe, though it's not that good. The lizards on crystal cave, when walking on invisible platform quickly turn back and swing and there's two.